# CakePHP 3.6: Count distinct records from table

Tags: php, cakephp, count, distinct

I am trying to achieve a distinct count on a table with a where condition.

This is what I have tried:

```
$customerServiceTypes = TableRegistry::get('CustomerServiceTypes');
$customers_count = $customerServiceTypes->find('all', array(
            'fields' => 'DISTINCT CustomerServiceType.customer_id',
            'conditions' => array("CustomerServiceTypes.service_type_id" => $id)))->count();
```

But its not working. I get `25` as result but it should be `2`. `Distinct` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$customerServiceTypes = TableRegistry::get('CustomerServiceTypes');
$customers_count = $customerServiceTypes->find()
     ->select(['customer_id'])
     ->distinct()
     ->where(['service_type_id =' => $id])->count();
```